# Error: "no such column: name..."

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an android app and this is the first time I use SQLite.

```
public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
public static final String KEY_TIME="time";
public static final String KEY_NUM="num";
public static final String KEY_PRICE="price";
private static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLENAME + " (" 
                                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                                    + KEY_NUM+" INTERGER,"
                                    + KEY_PRICE + " REAL,"
                                    + KEY_NAME + "TEXT,"
                                    + KEY_TIME +"TEXT)";

public Cursor fetchAllData(){
 return yueDb.query(DB_TABLENAME, new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NUM,KEY_PRICE,KEY_NAME,KEY_TIME},null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

The code throws an error when it call `fetchAllData()`. Eclipse tells me in the LogCat window:

> sqlite returned:error code=1,msg=no such column:name

I know the problem is about this function, but I really can't find where my code is wrong. If you get it, please teach me!

Comment: Post the stack trace of the error...

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space between NAME and TEXT ! ;)

This should solve the issue :

```
private static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLENAME + " (" 
                                        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
                                        + KEY_NUM+" INTEGER, "
                                        + KEY_PRICE + " REAL, "
                                        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
                                        + KEY_TIME +" TEXT)";
```

Comment: wow! THANKYOU Sephy!! It's useful! but why there must be a space?

Comment: If you don't have a space, your query looks like that :  CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, num INTEGER, price REAL, nameTEXT, time TEXT); Then how do you expect SQLite to understand "nameText", it will think it's a column name but you don't give the column type so you get an error.